# How to inject ng-repeat loop variable in ng-include content in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to build two table with same record structure.
One table is Main, other table is an Archiv.
The record is a bootstrap divs with col-sm-x structure with {{rec.Name}}, {{rec.Age}} etc.
From the record content I made a tablerecord.html template and i want to use in two different ng-repeat to build tables.

```
<div> ng-repeat="rec in MainTable"><record_template/></div> 
and
<div> ng-repeat="rec in Archiv""><record_template/></div>
```

To load the record template I use angular directive "recordTemplate".
How to inject "rec" variable in record_template?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the @input annotation in your directive component

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property

Answer (score 0):

```
    As i don't know how you written your directive. you can check the below link.

    http://jsbin.com/gopula/1/edit?html,js,output

and try this 

<div> ng-repeat="rec in MainTable" record_template ="rec"/></div> 
and
<div> ng-repeat="rec in Archiv" record_template="rec"/></div>

    Hope this will help you
```